# Dependency Injection with repositories

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Suppose I have an AlbumRepository class (albums table) and SongRepository class (songs table).

An album has several songs.

This is the album class (pseudo code)

```
class Album{
    protected Title;
    protected AlbumID;
    protected Metadata;

    public Song[] getSongs(){
        SongRepository songRepository = new SongRepository();
        return songRepository.whereAlbumID(this.AlbumID);
    }
}
```

I want to refactor this code so it doesn't instantiate SongRepository inside getSongs method,, but how do I do that?

I could require SongRepository in the getSongs method....

```
public Song[] getSongs(SongRepository songRepository){
    return songRepository.whereAlbumID(this.AlbumID);
}
```

But **I would really like to have getSongs with no parameters.**

Should I inject SongRepository in the **Album constructor**?

But then if someone uses an Album object without calling getSongs, then there is no need for SongRepository at all...

I guess the question is **Where should I inject SongRepository so the Album can use it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SongRepository` is a dependency of `Album`. As such, DI tells us that `Album` should not instantiate it directly, but rather be supplied with it. And since `Album` cannot function properly without a `SongRepository`, it should require an instance [to be provided to its constructor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) (as you suspected).

As for code that uses an `Album` without calling `getSongs` - why would that be a problem? The code that uses an `Album` shouldn't be the same code that *instantiate* the `Album` (object creation is a responsibility that should be delegated to the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).

Comment: Looking at the links now. Thanks for your time!